# Upload image to custom post type on wordpress frontend

Tags: php, wordpress, post, types

Im trying to upload an image to a custom post type called 'event_items'.
I have a custom field in there called 'event-image'. Id ideally like it to go there but if it used the custom post type featured image that would be fine.

Cant work out how or where to add it in. Have tried examples but none have worked as of yet. Thank you.

```
         <?php
         if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            $title=$_POST['title'];
            $body=$_POST['body'];
            $news_category=$_POST['region_names'];
            $state=$_POST['state'];

            // Create post object 
$post = array(
  'post_title'    => $title,
  'post_content'  => $body,
  'post_type'     =>'event_items',
  'post_status'   => 'pending',
  'post_author'   => 1
);

     // Insert the post into the database ref.https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post
$post_id = wp_insert_post( $post, $wp_error='' );

if($post_id!=0){

     ///upload image ref. 
     https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_meta

    ///ref. https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_handle_upload
    if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_handle_upload' ) ) require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
$uploadedfile = $_FILES['image'];
$upload_overrides = array( 'test_form' => false );
$movefile = wp_handle_upload( $uploadedfile, $upload_overrides );
if ( $movefile ) {
   // echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
   var_dump( $movefile);
} else {
    echo "Possible file upload attack!\n";
}


    add_post_meta($post_id, 'event_photo', $movefile['url'] );

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



    //insert taxonomy terms
    //ref. https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_object_terms

    ////for taxonomy 'news-category'//////////////////////////////
    $cat_ids = array($news_category);

    $cat_ids = array_map( 'intval', $cat_ids );
    $cat_ids = array_unique( $cat_ids );

    $term_taxonomy_ids = wp_set_object_terms($post_id, $cat_ids, 'region_names' );

    /////////////End for taxonomy 'news-category'//////////////////////////////



    ////for taxonomy 'st'//////////////////////////////
    $cat_ids2 = array($state);

    $cat_ids2 = array_map( 'intval', $cat_ids2 );
    $cat_ids2 = array_unique( $cat_ids2 );

    $term_taxonomy_ids2 = wp_set_object_terms($post_id, $cat_ids2, 'st' );

    /////////////End for taxonomy 'news-category'//////////////////////////////



    echo "New successfully added";
}   


         }


         ?>



         <h1>Add News</h1>

    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

      <table width="295" height="346" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="title" /></td>
  </tr>

          <tr>
    <td>Promo Excerpt</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="promo-title" /></td>
  </tr>


  <tr>
    <td>Description</td>
    <td><textarea name="body" ></textarea></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Upload Image </td>
    <td><input type="file" name="image" /></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>State</td>
    <td><?php
    //ref. https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms
     $terms2 = get_terms("st",'order_by=count&hide_empty=0');
 if ( !empty( $terms2 ) && !is_wp_error( $terms2 ) ){
     echo "<select name='state'>";
     echo "<option selected='selected'> Select </option>";
     foreach ( $terms2 as $term2 ) {
       echo "<option value='".$term2->term_id."'>" . $term2->name . "</option>";

     }
     echo "</select>";
 }
    ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Category </td>
    <td>

    <?php
    //ref. https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms
     $terms = get_terms("region_names",'order_by=count&hide_empty=0');
 if ( !empty( $terms ) && !is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
     echo "<select name='region_names'>";
         echo "<option selected='selected'> Select </option>";

     foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
       echo "<option value='".$term->term_id."'>" . $term->name . "</option>";

     }
     echo "</select>";
 }
    ?>

    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="submit"  value="Submit"/></td>
  </tr>

        </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i got it right , You want to support the featured image section in your custom post type, so all you got to do is just to add this line to your functions.php:

```
add_post_type_support( 'your Custom Post Type Name', 'thumbnail' );
```

It will add the featured image functionality , Then you can get post thumbnail in loop "`the_post_thumbnail()`" or using `get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id);` outside the loop .